# How to find the distribution of a function of two random variables?

Tags: distributions, self-study, random-variable, bivariate

I have the joint pdf

$$f(x_1,x_2)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{4}\;,\ -1<x_1,x_2<1\\ 0\;,\ \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

I have to find the distribution of $Y=\frac{X_2}{1+X_1^2}.$

I have tried to take the transformation $Y_1=\frac{X_2}{1+X_1^2}$ and $Y_2=1+X_1^2$, but I am having problems understanding.  Is this a good way to proceed? And what will be the range of the transformed variable? Can it be solved from these inequalities?

$$-1\lt \sqrt{Y_2-1}\lt 1\text{ and }-1\lt Y_1Y_2\lt 1$$

Comment: Because $\Pr(Y\le y) = \Pr(X_2 \le y(1 + X_1^2)),$ **draw a graph** of this region in the $(X_1,X_2)$ plane for some values of $y.$  You might find it easier first to solve this problem for $f(x_1,x_2)=1$ for $0\le x_1,x_2\le 1.$

Answer (score 3):

**Often, the most straightforward way to find the distribution of a variable defined in terms of other random variables is to compute its cumulative distribution function.**  For any number $y$ this function is the chance $Y\le y,$

$$F_Y(y) = \Pr(Y \le y) = \Pr\left(\frac{X_2}{1 + X_1^2}\le y\right) = \Pr(X_2 \le y(1 + X_1^2)).\tag{*}$$

It helps, as you suggest, to know what the "interesting" range of values of $y$ might be.  Two standard methods to find (or estimate) that range are

1. **Use mathematical facts** about inequalities and the possible values of the original random variables $(X_1, X_2)$.  For instance, because $1+X_1^2 \ge 1,$ necessarily $$|Y| = \bigg| \frac{X_2}{1 + X_1^2} \bigg| \le |X_2| \le 1.$$ This tells us there is *no* chance that $Y$ is smaller than $-1$ and *no* chance it exceeds $1.$  Thus, we only have to examine the possible values $-1 \le y \le 1.$
2. **Simulate some values.**  Here, for instance, is a straightforward simulation of a million values of $Y$ using `R` and a histogram showing the results:

   ```R
   n <- 1e6
   X1 <- runif(n, -1, 1)
   X2 <- runif(n, -1, 1)
   Y <- X2 / (1 + X1^2)
   hist(Y)
   ```

   [image: Figure 1: Histogram of simulated values of Y]

   Again, we discover we only need to work with values of $y$ between $-1$ and $1.$

This reduces the problem to finding the chances of events of the form $(*),$ $X_2 \le y(1 + X_1^2),$ for $-1\le y \le 1.$

It helps to **draw graphs of these events.**  They are bounded by contours of the function $Y(X_1, X_2)$ (which itself is defined *only* on the square shown here):

[image: Figure 2: Contour plot]

This enables you immediately to *see* the shapes of all these events.  That is because the event $Y \le y$ is comprised by all contours of the form $Y=y_0$ for $-1 \le y_0 \le y.$  In the plot, such an event will have one contour for its bound *along with the region below that contour.*

You can see there are four different shapes, as typified by these regions of the form $Y \le y:$

[image: Figure 3: Typical regions]

The boundaries of these shapes are pieces of horizontal and vertical lines, along with a piece of a *parabola.*

Now, in general, you need to integrate the density function of $(X_1,X_2)$ over any such shape.  But that's easy here, because that density is a constant $1/4:$ that is, *the probability of any event is one-quarter its area.*  So, use elementary Calculus to find the areas of these shapes: that will be your answer.

Finally, if you wish to find the *density* function of $Y,$ just differentiate $F_Y$ (as usual).  This is perhaps the hardest part of the problem, because it requires you to know several rules of differentiation--and it doesn't advance your understanding of the important concepts in this problem--so try to avoid this step if you can.